# There was a error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 52,Token in error = ) ]

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce

While trying to insert data to my SQl db i get the following error
    SqlCeException was unhandled:There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 52,Token in error = ) ]
My Line of code for retrieving data from table customerinfo is

```
SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source = ward.sdf;password=wardrobe");
con.Open();
SqlCeCommand com = con.CreateCommand();
com.CommandText= "select name from customerinfo where [id] =" + textBox1.Text;
SqlCeDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
reader.Read();
textBox2.Text = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
```

I am trying to get data from database and put it in a textbox. The error is apparently with line 5.

Comment: can you try this instead:
com.CommandText= "select name from customerinfo where [id] = '" + textBox1.Text + "'";

Comment: What kind of datatype is the field ID?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the datatype for the field ID it is difficult to give the correct answer.
But supposing that this field is of Text type then you should code with

```
com.CommandText= "select name from customerinfo where id =@id";
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", textBox1.Text);
SqlCeDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
if(reader.Read())
   textBox2.Text = (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("name")) ? reader[0].ToString() : string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am Using Visual Studio 2008 and my target device is WINCE device.

I had an Error "Parsing Query Error [Token line number=1 Token line Offset =29 Token in Error =1]" while inserting any value into SQL Server Database.

After Many trail I found out where actually my error was. Earlier while Giving Column Name I gave it like "Ch 1 " , "Ch 2" .
I just changed My Column Names and made it like "Ch1" and "Ch2" i.e. I removed the Space and it worked.

Here is my working code

```
private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlCeCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Tb (Ch1, Chl2) VALUES (?, ?)";

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("p1", SqlDbType.NText));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("p2", SqlDbType.Int));
            cmd.Parameters["p1"].Size = 50;

            cmd.Prepare();
            cmd.Parameters["p1"].Value =textBox1.Text;
            cmd.Parameters["p2"].Value =textBox2.Text;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            displayTable();

        }
  private void displayTable()
        {
           SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM Tb", con1);
           SqlCeDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
           DataTable table = new DataTable();
           table.Columns.Add("Ch1", typeof(int));
           table.Columns.Add("Ch2", typeof(string));

           while (reader.Read())
           {
               table.Rows.Add(reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetString(1));
           }
           reader.Close();
           dataGrid1.DataSource = table;


        }
```

Hope it will help you .

Refer bellow link for further details
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226134%28v=sql.80%29.aspx